# Accessing multiple result sets using ExecuteXmlReader()

Tags: c#

How do I access the second, when using ExecuteXmlReader(), ordinarily I would use NextResult() but that isn't available with Xml.XmlReader.

SQL

```
select * from table1 for xml auto
select * from table2 for xml auto
```

C#

```
using (System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader())
{
    while (xmlReader.Read())
    {
           while (xmlReader.ReadState != System.Xml.ReadState.EndOfFile)    
           {
           result =  xmlReader.ReadOuterXml();                   
           } 
           //do something with each result
     }
}
```

Comment: See my response at following posting.  I like to use a combionation of xmlreader and xml linq.  I assume the results would be one row of the SQL Database.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34274568/how-to-read-an-xml-file-by-using-xmlreader-in-c-sharp